# How to return an array of courses and rooms where the room capacity is greater than or equal to the course enrollment

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling with how to return an array of courses that includes an array of rooms with a capacity that is greater than or equal to the course enrollment of each course.

The following code returns an array in the structure I want, but only the last value. I have tried array_merge_recursive, and either get an error or only the last value again.

I created the arrays like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$course_query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'courses', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
$courses = $course_query1->posts;
$course_array1 = array();

foreach($courses as $i => $course) {
    $course_array1[$i]['course_name'] = $course->post_name;
    $course_array1[$i]['cap'] = $course->course_enrolled;
    $course_array1[$i]['cap_array'] = $course->room_matches;

}

$room_query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'jost_rooms', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
$rooms = $room_query1->posts;
$room_array1 = array();

foreach($rooms as $i => $room) {
        $room_array1[$i]['room_name'] = $room->post_name;
        $room_array1[$i]['cap'] = $room->room_capacity;

}
```

And created the function like so:

```
function compare_capacities10($array1, $array2){

for($c = 0; $c < count($array1); $c++) {

    foreach($array1[$c] as $ckey => $ccap) {
                if ($ckey == 'cap') {

                for($r = 0; $r < count($array2); $r++) {
                        foreach($array2[$r] as $rkey => $rcap) {
                            if (($rkey == 'cap') && ($rcap >= $ccap)){
                                //this structure is right but only returns last value
                                $result = array($ckey, $ccap, array($rkey, $rcap) );
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
return $result;
}

$capacity_array10 =  compare_capacities10 ($course_array1, 
$room_array1);
print_r($capacity_array10);
```

**EDIT:**

I'm adding the code below, because it's achieving the same thing as above, but is better in WordPress because I can add other key-values to the display:

```
  $courses = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'courses', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'  ) );


    if ( $courses->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $courses->have_posts() ) {
        $courses->the_post();

         $enr = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'course_enrolled' , true);
         $cname = get_the_title();

         $rooms = new WP_Query(
                  array(
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'post_type' => 'rooms',
                  'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'key' => 'room_capacity',
                        'posts_per_page' => '-1',

                        'value' => $enr,
                        'compare' => '>='
                        )
                      )
                    )
          );
          if ( $rooms->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $rooms->have_posts() ) {
                $rooms->the_post();


                $rname = get_the_title();
                $cap = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'room_capacity' , true);
                echo 'cname: ' . $cname . ' ' . 'enrolled: ' . $enr . 'rname: ' . $rname.  'capacity: ' . $cap . '<br/>';

              }
            }

      }
    } else {
        echo "Loop not working";
      }

   wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: `$result = array($ckey, $ccap, array($rkey, $rcap) );` should be `$result[] = array($ckey, $ccap, array($rkey, $rcap) );`

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely for the problem I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to use array_push there.

[Here's a link to the doc.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Right now you're overwriting the $result variable each iteration.